# How to reformat an int when parsing a csv (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, csv

Trying to parse a column for seat capacity. In the csv file i edited the numbers to be in the form 30000 instead of 30,000. When parsing the file I still get the output as being 30, 000. How can i get rid of the space and the comma between the 0 two zeroes?

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""30"
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

Code:

```
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      {
           String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
           String university = "%"+b[3]+"%";

           preparedStatement = connect
                  .prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM usale.university WHERE title LIKE ?");
                   preparedStatement.setString(1, university);


              resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
              if(resultSet.next())
              {
              universityid = resultSet.getInt("id");
              }
               System.out.println(b[0]+", "+b[1]+", "+b[2]+", "+b[3]+", "+b[4]+", "+b[5]+", "+universityid);

               if(universityid != 0)
               {
                   preparedStatement = connect
                              .prepareStatement("insert into usale.stadium(stadium_id, stadium_name, seat_availability, stadium_capacity, university_id, stadium_city) "
                                    + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
                          preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(b[0]));
                          preparedStatement.setString(2, b[1]);
                          preparedStatement.setString(3, "all-seater");
                          preparedStatement.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(b[4]));
                          preparedStatement.setInt(5, universityid);
                          preparedStatement.setString(6, b[2]);
                          preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
               }


            universityid = 0;
      }
```

edit (here is some sample csv data):

1,Aggie Memorial Stadium,Las Cruces,New Mexico State,"30343",all-seater,

2,Alamodome,San Antonio,UTSA,"65000",all-seater,

3,Albertsons Stadium,Boise,Boise State,"37000",all-seater,

Comment: Could you attach some example data from your csv? What is your separator string (`splitBy`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your exception trace your integer contains double quotes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""30"
```

You can remove them using:

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Just in case there is an extra space, which i can't see but you have mentioned in your question. To remove trailing spaces, you can add trim also:

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\"", "").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to get rid of the commas and spaces, you could use `replaceAll` which in turn uses regular expressions to remove commas:

```
numberString.replaceAll("[, ]", "");
```

or

```
numberString.replaceAll("[,\\s]", "");
```

Or, in your case, it looks like `30,000` represents some sort of currency or transaction. **[`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance())**'s `getCurrencyInstance()` might come in handy here:

```
Number number = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse(numberString);
numberString = number.toString();
```